# Plot Graph Based Pair of Columns

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset like this.

```
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| string1 | string2 |    col3    |   col4     |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| abc     | xyz     | random_num | random_num |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| abc     | mno     | random_num | random_num |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| abc     | xyz     | random_num | random_num |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

So I have to plot `col3 vs. col4` where the pair `string1, string2` are repeating, meaning, say for the example above, my plots will be the 1st and 3rd row. 
`string1, string2` can have different but reappearing values, that is there will be several unique `string1, string2`  values appearing more than once so that we can plot `col3 vs. col4`.
This data set is huge and contains many repeating `string1, string2` pairs.

How to do that! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table` objects. Example:

```
c1 = {'abc'; 'def'; 'abc'};
c2 = {1;2;3};

T = table(c1,c2,'VariableNames',{'c1','c2'});
filteredData = T(strcmp(T.c1,'abc'),:)
```

You can of course filter for the different values (you can get the unique set of values in `c1` using `unique(T.c1)`, filter on those values, and then plot the data as you please.